# When you are looking for someone to carry your load / burden at a hotel, at an airport etc

Tags: idiomatic-language

Imagine you have just arrived to a hotel and checked in. You have two big and heavy suitcases and you are looking for the carrier. I am going to find out if my self-made sentence works here naturally and if not what a native speaker would say here to indicate exactly what I am going to convey:

> Who can I ask to carry my burden / load?

It seems to me that my sentence structurally and grammatically is correct, but I have no idea if it is natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but semantically wrong. If you say

> Who can I ask to carry my burden?

"Burden" can have several different meanings not least of which is an "emotional burden".

Your sentence should probably be

> Whom can I ask to help me with my bags?

Once you check-in, the hotel will usually say to you

> One of our porters will help you with your bags and show you to your room.

The person you are looking for is the **porter**.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter. As usual, informative. But to clarify it, please answer this question of mine too. What about the sentence: **"That truck is carrying a heavy (load / burden)"** Does the word "load" works better here too? If yes, then does the sentence sounds natural and idiomatic?

Comment: "Truck carrying a heavy load" is natural and idiomatic. "Truck carrying a heavy burden." is not. When you put stuff on/in a truck, you "load it up".